# Confusion about fputs()

Tags: c, fputs

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char str[100];
   printf("Enter a string: ");
   fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
   fputs("Liverpool", stdout);
   fputs("Manchester", stdout);
   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

Enter a string : punch
LiverpoolManchester

But, when I am taking the input from the user, it is not giving the expected output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char str[100];
   printf("Enter a string: ");
   fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
   fputs(str, stdout);
   fputs(str, stdout);
   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

Enter a string : punch
punch
punch

The only change between the two codes is, I was specifying the string in the previous one and in the latter, I am taking the input from the user. Can anybody tell me the reason behind this ??

Comment: "it is not giving the expected output". What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: The difference in the output clearly implies that the string in the second example contains a newline character.  It has to.  And sure enough, if you look at the man page for `fgets`, it *says* that it includes the newline character.  Try to read the man page for a function more carefully.  It describes exactly how `fgets` works.

Answer (score 2):

The [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) function reads up until and *including* the newline.

So the buffer you pass to `fputs` will include the newline from the `fgets` call, which of course will be adding new lines in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these two links on the functions `fgets` and `fputs`.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fputs/

It will help you more to read those yourself definitely. But it seems that when using `fputs` it doesn't automatically append a newline character `\n` at the end of your string.

In your first example by specifying the specific string hard coded the newline isn't added. When you use fgets it WILL automatically append a `\n` at the end. So when you output `str` instead of `"Liverpool"` or `"Manchester"` it's storing `"punch\n"` not just `"punch"`.